# javascript for loop not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

I know this is really basic but I am new to Javascript

This is a piece of code from a battleship game I am working on for a class

```
function displayMyBoats(ship){

    for (var i = 0; i<ship.length; i++) 
    {
        alert("ship.length = " + ship.length);
        alert("Ship[i]= " + ship[i]);
        document.getElementById( "Set_" + ship[i] ).src = fnImageShip;
        alert("i = " + i);
    }
}
```

I am testing with a ship array that is 5 elements. Everything works fine until it reaches 5, then all of a sudden it thinks the length of the array is 8.

There is no code to increase the length of ship array, so what would cause it to add to the length of the array?

The alerts are my testing to see what all the values are at.

Comment: It should be some other part of the code which causes this.  I mean, there could be event handlers which trigger `onpropertychange`  of `Set_" + ship[i]` for example.

Comment: It's hard to say anything from this -- can you show where you create the array and pass it to the function?

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/wb4TW/ sfrocks is correct. This code works fine. Something else must be causing an error.

Answer (score 2):

To give you a hint, try adding an alert whenever your script is either entering or exiting the `displayMyBoats()`. Suddenly jumping to 8 indicates that it's entering the method a second time, this time with a ship of len 8.

Confirm or deny this theory by adding this alert *after* your for loop block:

```
 alert('exiting displayMyBoats()');`
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you see more if you use console.log(ship); instead of alert(); - if you are using Firebug/Console.